# Taxation of dividends/CGs/interest arising in US for Indian citizen resident in India

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, irs

I am an Indian citizen and used to live in USA. I had opened both regular bank/brokerage account and IRA (retirement brokerage) account too.

Now, I live in India and a 'Resident & Ordinary Resident' for tax purposes. How much % tax should I pay to US/India for income generated in US for:

- interest income
- dividend
- capital gains

Taxes are currently not withheld by US bank/brokers on my interest income/dividend/capital gains.

Thanks for your time!